# Assembly partial registers

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I've read an explanation about partial registers
And wanted to understand why this code:

```
XOR EAX,EAX
MOV AX, BX
```

will work only if eax holds a non signed positive number
But if there is a signed negative number in eax
You need to make sure the new bits youve added are 111.., i understand it has something to do with two's complement
But I still don't understand it.

**Edit:**

I understand the code above will work either way
I wanted to understand why would you need to pad those extra 1's (when I don't zero eax)

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in `EAX` since that gets zeroed. What matters is what's in `BX`. Presumably what you are talking about is sign extending `BX` into `EAX`, but this code does zero extension. For non-negative numbers that of course is equivalent to sign extension since the sign bit is `0`.

Comment: What you should actually do here is `movzx eax, bx`, or `movsx eax, bx`, for zero or sign extension.  Or, that's your reference point for reasoning about what sequences are equivalent to which instruction.

Comment: Well actually im trying to understand the usage of movzx, i mean why do you even need to pad those extra 1s

Comment: If you don't zero `eax` then whatever is left in the top half remains there. It might not even be all zeroes or ones, so no telling what  the resulting 32 bit number would be. A 16 bit number sign extended to 32 bit will have a copy of the sign bit in the top half, which is all ones for a negative number, and all zeroes otherwise.

Comment: You need to zero-extend or sign-extend if you want to use a narrow integer as an array index or something.  e.g. `int foo(short a) { return LUT[a]; }` needs to sign-extend `a` into a 32bit register so you can use it in a 32bit or 64bit effective address, like `[LUT + eax*4]`.  If `a` was unsigned, you'd zero-extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More often than not, you work with unsigned numbers while hand-writing assembly. Of course, this is not always the case, and C's `int` promotions should be implemented somehow, right?

Let's start by explaining two's complement at the bit level. First of all, the topmost bit, when set, indicates a negative number, and when clear, a non-negative nne. If it's clear, the stuff acts as you would expect. That is, `0` is written `0x00000000`, and `2147483647` is written `0x7FFFFFFF`. However, for any negative number `N`, in order to get its absolute value, you have to do `~N-1`, with all respective wrap-arounds. This lends into `-1` being written `0xFF`, and `-2147483648` being written `0x80`. This has some nice side effects, such that `-0 == 0` and addition/subtraction is the same operation for all numbers.

Now, to your code....

```
XOR EAX,EAX
```

As a mathematical rule, exclusive-OR'ing something against itself will always yield zero as a result. So, you can think of this like an optimized `MOV EAX, 0'. BTW, you may want to read [why XOR is better for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and). Then...

```
MOV AX, BX
```

`MOV` is an instruction that literally means "to copy the bits as-is". That is, all cleared bits in the source are respectively cleared in the destination, and all set bits in the source are respectively set in the destination. In this case, `AX` will now contain an exact copy of `BX`'s contents. In the x86 architecture, `EAX`, `EBX`, `ECX`, and `EDX` are all divided this way...

```
 ________________ ________ ____ ____
|      ERX       |   RX   | RH | RL |
|________________|________|____|____|
 \_________________________________/
          |       \________________/
      32 bits              |    \__/
                       16 bits   ||
                               8 bits
```

This means that for each register `R`, `ERX` represents all of its 32 bits, `RX` represents its lower 16 bits, `RH` represents the higher byte of its lower 16 bits, and `RL` represents the lower byte of its lower 16 bits. Thus, returning to your code, and assuming `BX` contains `0xFFFF` (`-1` in two's complement), this is what happens...

```
 ______________ __________________________________ __________________________________
| Instruction  | EAX                              | EBX                              |
|______________|__________________________________|__________________________________|
| XOR EAX, EAX | 00000000000000000000000000000000 | 00000000000000001111111111111111 |
|______________|__________________________________|__________________________________|
| MOV AX, BX   | 00000000000000001111111111111111 | 00000000000000001111111111111111 |
|______________|__________________________________|__________________________________|
```

Then, if we interpret `AX` as a two's complement number, we get the right answer, that is, `-1`. However, if we interpret `EAX` as a two's complement number, we get a *wrong* answer, `65535`. In order to do this correctly, we have to do a sign-extended move. This means that the instruction will take into account the fact that the value is in two's complement form and will thus manipulate it correctly. See, for instance...

```
 _______________ __________________________________ __________________________________
| Instruction   | EAX                              | EBX                              |
|_______________|__________________________________|__________________________________|
| MOVSX EAX, BX | 11111111111111111111111111111111 | 00000000000000001111111111111111 |
|_______________|__________________________________|__________________________________|
```

Now, interpreting `EAX` as a 32-bit two's complement number will yield the right answer, `-1`. This is (yet) another advantage of two's complement. You can sign-extend by just copying the top-most bit as many times as needed.

Comment: [This explains why `xor`-zeroing is better than `mov reg, 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  You might want to incorporate that link into your answer.  Also, the x86 tag wiki has some links to register diagrams like ASCII one you created for a single register.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you keep putting `I hope this has led a light on you!` back in after moderators take it out?  It's not even a meaningful English sentence.  You can say "I hope this has shed some light on your problem", i.e. illuminated / clarified what was previously unclear / hard to see.  But that doesn't sound very cool.  I can't think of a good way to phrase what I think you're trying to say.  I think it's redundant anyway; everyone that posts answers does it to try to help people.  Either the asker of the question, or more often to help other people that read it in future.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I didn't intended to reverse it. It was... kind of a mess. Undone that.